# transparent text, such that floats and footnotes are affected correctly

Tags: floats, color, footnotes, transparency, transparent

My question is very similar to [Recolor text, such that floats and footnotes are affected correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449822/recolor-text-such-that-floats-and-footnotes-are-affected-correctly), but I am using transparent text instead of colored text.
(I do not simply use grey text because I am using many colored `hyperref` links that should change their color as well in transparent mode.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm,paperheight=3.3cm,scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This text is black.
\footnote{\transparent{1}I can easily control the transparency of footnotes.}

\begingroup
\transparent{0.2}
This text is transparent%
\footnote{\transparent{0.5}I can always control the transparency of footnotes.},
but the line below that separates the text from the footnote and the footnote-numbers should be black, but they transparent and I don't know how to control their transparency  
\clearpage
This text is still transparent.
\footnote{\transparent{0.1}I can still easily control the transparency of footnotes.}
\endgroup

This text is correctly black again.
\vfill
The line (and numbers) below is correctly black again
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I change the separating line and the numbers to black?
(In real worls examples I use normal automatic page-breaks and not `\clearpage`, of course)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `\normalcolor` to also reset the transparency, then the behaviour is the same as your linked question.

Add this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\normalcolor{\let\current@color\default@color\set@color\transparent{1}}
\makeatother
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=9cm,paperheight=3.3cm,scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\normalcolor{\let\current@color\default@color\set@color\transparent{1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This text is black.
\footnote{\transparent{1}I can easily control the transparency of footnotes.}

\begingroup
\transparent{0.2}
This text is transparent%
\footnote{\transparent{0.5}I can always control the transparency of footnotes.},
but the line below that separates the text from the footnote and the footnote-numbers should be black, but they transparent and I don't know how to control their transparency  
\clearpage
This text is still transparent.
\footnote{\transparent{0.1}I can still easily control the transparency of footnotes.}
\endgroup

This text is correctly black again.
\vfill
The line (and numbers) below is correctly black again
\end{document}
```

### Page 1

[image: MWE output page 1]

### Page 2

[image: MWE output page 2]

Comment: I do not fully understand how it works but it works. What are the side-effects? When I use `\normalcolor` explicitly it changes the transparency too now, but is `\normalcolor` often used by LaTeX internally? How was `\normalcolor` defined before you redefine it. Is your solution equivalent to `\let\oldnormalcolor\normalcolor` together with `\renewcommand{\normalcolor}{\oldnormalcolor\transparent{1}}`. For me this looks safer (more compatible) and easier to read. Which version is better?

Comment: @Jakob, it was defined the same but without `\transparent{1}` on the end, so yes you can do what you have suggested. `\normalcolor` is used often by LaTeX, but I think it should be OK to redefine it this way, since in your case you want normal colour to be with 0% transparency.